# Python Subprocess.check_output/run throws exception (WINDOWS)

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, command-line-interface

I'm trying to invoke Command lines with Subprocess module but i keep getting the exception : [WinError 2] The System cannot find the file specified

```
import subprocess
import os


class SlnFinder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.AllSln = {}
        def Get_All_Sln(self):
          
            raw_sln_paths = subprocess.check_output("cd "+os.getcwd() +" Everything-CLI && es.exe \"*.sln\"").decode('utf-8').split("\n")
```

Comment: btw, the ".decode(...).split(...)" suffix doesnt trigger the exception

Comment: Always provide a complete [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example"). Please do not post links to code and reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Ok @itprorh66, i have changed it as your orders.
do you have any helpful insights regarding my question?

Comment: Try with [`shell=True`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) as `cd` and `&&` are shell commands ...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're file isnt found in that directory. You can try doing

```
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
raw_sln_paths = subprocess.run("cd " + cwd + "/Everything-CLI...
```

I hope this works for you!

Comment: it doesnt work :(

Comment: @Mr.Mysiques can you please send log?

Comment: no log, just the aforementioned exception